# Items on listview repeat on pull to refresh xamarinforms

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, pull-to-refresh

I am trying to implement pull to refresh functionality in ListView in xamarinforms app. The data is coming from webapi. When I pull to refresh it, the app appends the new result in the ListView (Just on UI not in ViewModel). In View Model the ListItemsCount does not change but on UI it repeats all the elements.

Here is my ListViewCode in XAML Code:

```
<ListView x:Name="ImageListView" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding portfolioModelList}" 
                      CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
                      SeparatorVisibility="None" 
                      HasUnevenRows="True"
                      IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" 
                      IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}"
                      RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshPortfolioCommand}" 
                      SelectionMode="None">
```

Here is my Command Code in ViewModel:

```
public Command RefreshPortfolioCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(async () =>
            {
                IsRefreshing = true;

                portfolioList.Clear();

                var client = new RestClient(Constant.baseUrl);
                var request = new RestRequest("myapi/getlistitems", Method.GET);
                var apiDocs = await client.ExecuteGetAsync<ObservableCollection<clsDocument>>(request);
                var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<clsDocument>>(apiDocs.Content);
                portfolioList = x;
                IsRefreshing = false;

            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: No.. You may be able to refactor some of your Xamarin Android code and use it in a Forms project, but there is no way to just convert or reuse these projects without a significant amount of work.